# Applying factor labels based on a condition in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with a variable 'education' which is coded differently in each of the three countries included, for example:

| Code | Country 1 | Country 2 | Country 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | No education | No education | No education |
| 2 | Primary | Primary | Islamic education |
| 3 | Secondary | Secondary | Primary |
| 4 | NA | NA | Secondary |

I need to apply factor levels, which are different for each country.

Below is my attempt, but it doesn't appear to work:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Country = sample(c("Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
  Education_1 = sample(1:4)
)

df$Education <- 
  if(df$Country == "Country1") {
    factor(df$Education,
           levels = c(1:4),
           labels = c("No education", "Primary", "Secondary", "NA"))
  } else if (df$Country == "Country2") {
    factor(df$Education,
           levels = c(1:4),
           labels = c("No education", "Primary", "Secondary", "NA"))
  } else {
    factor(df$Education, 
           levels = c(1:4), 
           labels = c("No education", "Islamic education", "Primary", "Secondary")
    )
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: The approach taken probably depends on what do you want to do with the data and factors?  If you could share this that would be helpful. Typically this would be put into long format so you only need one variable with the education values and you could manage this with 5 levels.

Comment: I need to apply levels to the factor for descriptive/ modelling analysis. The problem I am trying to overcome is that code 2 (for example) means something different depending on the country, so I'm wondering how to account for that

Comment: maybe using a five level code along the lines of `c(1 = "No education", 2 = "Islamic education", 3 = "Primary", 4 = "Secondary", 999 = NA)` would resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal- but I have inherited this file with the funky coding- I can separate the countries though, apply levels based on the country and remerge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps? This takes the data from the table mapping countries with the education code and the education category and converts it to long format.

Then use a left join to the two column dataframe with countries and education codes.

You could use the resulting column with education type as a string or the codes could be recoded to be consistent.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)


df <- data.frame(
  Country = sample(c("Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
  Education_1 = sample(1:4))


df_ed <- structure(list(Code = 1:4, Country.1 = c("No education", "Primary", 
                                                      "Secondary", NA), Country.2 = c("No education", "Primary", "Secondary", 
                                                                                      NA), Country.3 = c("No education", "Islamic education", "Primary", 
                                                                                                         "Secondary")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)) 

df_levels  <-  
  df_ed %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Code) %>% 
  mutate(name = str_replace(name, "\\.", " "))

df1 <- 
  df %>% 
  left_join(df_levels, by = c("Country" = "name", "Education_1" = "Code"))

head(df1)
#>     Country Education_1        value
#> 1 Country 1           3    Secondary
#> 2 Country 2           4         <NA>
#> 3 Country 3           1 No education
#> 4 Country 1           2      Primary
#> 5 Country 3           3      Primary
#> 6 Country 2           4         <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>